# How to prove False from obviously contradictory assumptions

Tags: coq, proof

Suppose I want to prove following Theorem:

```
Theorem succ_neq_zero : forall n m: nat, S n = m -> 0 = m -> False.
```

This one is trivial since `m` cannot be both successor and zero, as assumed. However I found it quite tricky to prove it, and I don't know how to make it without an auxiliary lemma:

```
Lemma succ_neq_zero_lemma : forall n : nat, O = S n -> False.
Proof.
  intros.
  inversion H.
Qed.

Theorem succ_neq_zero : forall n m: nat, S n = m -> 0 = m -> False.
Proof.
  intros.
  symmetry in H.
  apply (succ_neq_zero_lemma n).
  transitivity m.
  assumption.
  assumption.
Qed.
```

I am pretty sure there is a better way to prove this. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to substitute for `m` in the first equation:

```
Theorem succ_neq_zero : forall n m: nat, S n = m -> 0 = m -> False.
Proof.
intros n m H1 H2; rewrite <- H2 in H1; inversion H1.
Qed.
```

Comment: Or a bit more concise yet still explicit: `intros n m H <-; discriminate H.` (less explicit `intros; subst; discriminate.` works too).

Answer (score 6):

There's a very easy way to prove it:

```
Theorem succ_neq_zero : forall n m: nat, S n = m -> 0 = m -> False.
Proof.
  congruence.
Qed.
```

The `congruence` tactic is a decision procedure for ground equalities on uninterpreted symbols. It's complete for uninterpreted symbols and for constructors, so in cases like this one, it can prove that the equality `0 = m` is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

It might be useful to know how congruence works.

To prove that two terms constructed by different constructors are in fact different, just create a function that returns `True` in one case and `False` in the other cases, and then use it to prove `True = False`.  I think this is explained in [*Coq'Art*](https://www.labri.fr/perso/casteran/CoqArt/)

```
Example not_congruent: 0 <> 1.
  intros C. (* now our goal is 'False' *)
  pose (fun m=>match m with 0=>True |S _=>False end) as f.
  assert (Contra: f 1 = f 0) by (rewrite C; reflexivity).
  now replace False with True by Contra.
Qed.
```