# Not equal succesors in Coq

Tags: coq, proof

I am trying to prove the following lemma in Coq:

```
Lemma not_eq_S2: forall m n, S m <> S n -> m <> n.
```

It seems easy but I do not find how to finish the proof. Can anybody help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The thing to know is that in Coq, a negation is a function that implies `False`, so the `S m <> S n` is really `S m = S n -> False`.  So instead of proving `n <> m` we can introduce the `n = m` (we can either unfold `not` or tell `intros` explicitly to do it) and get the goal `False` instead.  But with `n = m` in the context we can rewrite `HS: S n <> S m` into `HS: S n <> S n`, which can be handled by `auto`, or many other tactics such as `apply HS. reflexivity.` or `congruence.` etc.

```
Lemma not_eq_S2: forall m n, S m <> S n -> m <> n.

Proof. intros m n HS HC. 
  rewrite HC in HS. auto.
Qed.
```

Comment: This was helpful for me to prove Some x <> None. I was stumped because I didn't understand what the <> symbol actually meant. With your help I found that this worked: unfold not; intros; discriminate.

Comment: You might also want to checkout this comment about how such proofs work under-the-hood: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286679/how-to-prove-false-from-obviously-contradictory-assumptions/49730456#49730456

Answer (score 2):

It's really easy (but the negation makes it a bit confusing).

```
Lemma not_eq_S2: forall m n, S m <> S n -> m <> n.
Proof.
  unfold not.      (*                             |- ... -> False *)
  intros m n H C.  (* ..., H : S m = S n -> False |- False *)
  apply H.         (* ...                         |- S m = S n *)
  (* f_equal gets rid of functions applied on both sides of an equality,
     this is probably what you didn't find *)
  (* basically, f_equal turns a goal [f a = f b] into [a = b] *)
  f_equal.         (* ..., C : m = n              |- m = n *)
  exact C.
Qed.
```