# How to prove that (0 = 2) -> false in Coq?

Tags: logic, coq

In a proof of one lemma I eventually reached a state, where

I have a premise

`H : 0 = 2`

and I have to prove

`false`.

**Question**: how to infer that the premise `H` is false to conclude the proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `discriminate` tactic can deal with situations like that. I believe that `easy` also works, as does `congruence`, which are a bit more general than `discriminate`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to understand how it works "behind the scenes", [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49730456/304284) may be useful.